# Set-SPAppDomain local

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, error, windows-server, server

How can I set a local domain for:

```
Set-SPAppDomain "mydomain"
Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name "mydomain"
```

"mydomain" is just an example.

Now for the second command I'm getting this error:

> Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName : The server did not provide a meaningful reply;
>   this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an
>    internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that the App Management Service and the Subscription Settings Service are both running.

Use Get-SPServiceInstance to get a list of services.